# Export/Import of custom block in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How to export/import custom block in drupal 8/9?

Content of the custom block to be made changes in other user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Structure Sync https://www.drupal.org/project/structure_sync module to export and import your custom blocks, taxonomy terms, and menu links.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Content synchronization](https://www.drupal.org/docs/extending-drupal/contributed-modules/contributed-module-documentation/mix/content-synchronization) feature from the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module, which allows you to export/import and recreate block contents, menu item links and taxonomy terms between environments (sites)

You can easily choose which items to sync via UI like below:
[image]